# image of injective function from $Z_{pqr} to Z_{pq}×Z_{qr}×Z_{rp}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Fix three distinct primes $p, q, r$, prove that the map
>
> $Z_{pqr}→Z_{pq}×Z_{qr}×Z_{pr}$ by $[x]_{pqr} → ([x]_{pq}, [x]_{qr}, [x]_{pr})$
>
> is injective and determine its image.

**My attempt:**

To prove it is injective, I said let there be $x$ and $y$ such that $[x]_{pq}=[y]_{pq}$. This means $pq|(x−y)$ So, one of $p$ or $q$ must divide $(x−y)$. Similarly, either $p$ or $r$ and either $q$ or $r$ must divide $x−y$ as well. Therefore, one of $p,q,r$ must divide $x−y$.

This implies $pqr|(x−y)$, So, $[x]_{pqr}=[y]_{pqr}$ This proves that the function is injective (if I'm correct in my implications).

Now, how do I determine its image?
Maybe I can use the chinese remainder theorem and establish a bijection from $Z_p×Z_q×Z_r$ to $Z_{pqr}$ and use that somehow, but can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is the kernel of the map?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, I apologize.

Comment: Is the map a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, it is. Could you please elaborate on how that should help me?

Comment: **Hint:** A homomorphism $\varphi: G\to H$ is injective iff $\ker \varphi=\{0_G\}$.

Comment: But how does this help me determine which elements this function (homomorphism in this case) maps to? I have not been formally introduced to group theory, so I'm trying to make sense of the things you're saying as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer indicates, your proof is not quite right.  You are not trying to show that a single prime divides $x-y$, but that all three do.

As for characterizing the image, suppose we have some triple $(a,b,c) \in Z_{pq}\times Z_{qr} \times Z_{pr}$.  How can we check that it actually came from an element $x\in Z_{pqr}$?  One approach is to compare, for example, the image of $a$ in $Z_p$ with the image of $c$ in $Z_p$.  If there is such an $x$, these two things have to be equal.

Do the same thing for $Z_q$ and $Z_r$ you'll have three conditions on $(a,b,c)$.  To actually construct $x$ using these conditions, you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

More explicitly, consider the map $\psi(a,b,c) = (a-b, b-c, c-a) \in Z_q \times Z_r \times Z_p$.  Prove that everything in the image of your map $\phi$ is in the kernel of $\psi$ (manipulate the definitions), and prove that everything in the kernel of $\psi$ is in the image of $\phi$ (requires the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: How do the images of $a$ and $c$ in $Z_p$ being equal imply that $x$ must be in $Z_{pqr}$?

Comment: It doesn't, you need to use the same conditions for $Z_q$ and $Z_r$.  And the point isn't to show anything about $x$, which isn't given--the point is to construct $x$ in the first place!  Here is an additional hint: use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to choose some integer $x$ that has the right remainders modulo $p$, $q$, and $r$.

Comment: But what is this "right remainder" you mention?

Comment: The point is to use the condition $a \equiv c \pmod{p}$ and construct an $x$ that is congruent to both.

Comment: You say "if there is such an x, these two things have to be equal". Why is that?

Comment: Because reducing modulo $pq$ then reducing modulo $p$ is the same as reducing modulo $pr$ then reducing modulo $p$.  Both are equivalent to just reducing modulo $p$!

Comment: @childishsadbino I added a more explicit description in my answer that might be helpful.  There are two directions to prove--let me know if one of them gives you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of the first part is completely wrong. "One of $p,q,r$ divides ..." does not imply "All of $p,q,r$ divide ...". I suggest you fix that problem first before trying the second part. Also, it is easy and has nothing to do with homomorphisms and kernels. **Hint**: if $x \mid n$ then $n = ax$ for some integer $a$, and if $y \mid n$ such that $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, then $n \equiv ax \pmod{y}$ and $x$ is invertible mod $y$, so ...

I'm not sure what the question means by saying "determine its image", since it seems the simplest description of its image is literally $\{ ([x]_{pq},[x]_{qr},[x]_{rp}) : x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

If you wish to invert the mapping, note that $x \bmod p = ( x \bmod pq ) \bmod p = ( x \bmod rp ) \bmod p$, so each triple $(a,b,c)$ in the image must satisfy $p \mid c-a$ and $q \mid a-b$ and $r \mid b-c$. What else can we say?

Comment: well, $Z_{pqr}$ has pqr number of elements and the set it is mapping to has $(pqr)^2$ elements, so the question is asking to specify which elements it hits.

Comment: @childishsadbino: I know that, and I did literally that in my answer. I don't see a simpler way to "specify which elements it hits" than simply saying it is the image of the given function. I would say that that question is too vague to be properly answerable.

Comment: @user21820 See my answer.  There is a nice characterization of the image intrinsic to the target: it consists of the triples $(a,b,c)$ that map to zero under the map $(a,b,c) \mapsto (a-b, b-c, c-a) \in Z_q \times Z_r \times Z_p$.